# Python: Read Content of Hidden HTML Table

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

On this webpage there is a "Show Study location" tab, when I click the tab it shows the entire location list and changes the web-address which I included in this program. and when I run the program to print out the entire location list, I get this result:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen('https://clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/show/study/NCT01718158?term=NCT01718158&rank=1&show_locs=Y#locn').read())

for row in soup('table')[5].findAll('tr'):
    tds = row('td')
    if len(tds)<2:
        continue
    print tds[0].string, tds[1].string  #, '\n'.join(filter(unicode.strip, tds[1].strings))

Local Institution None
Local Institution None
Local Institution None
Local Institution None
Local Institution None
```

and so on..... leaving the rest of the information out. I feel I am missing something here. my result should be:

```
United States, California
Va Long Beach Healthcare System 
Long Beach, California, United States, 90822
United States, Georgia
Gastrointestinal Specialists Of Georgia Pc  
Marietta, Georgia, United States, 30060
United States, New York
Weill Cornell Medical College
```

and so forth. I want to print out the entire location list.

Comment: It looks like the content may be modified based on user agent or maybe populated by JavaScript. `wget --no-check-certificate https://clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/show/study/NCT01718158?term=NCT01718158&rank=1&s
how_locs=Y` delivers me a file that doesn't have any of the locations you're looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The local institutes are in rows with just one table cell, but you are skipping those.

Perhaps you need to extract the data from all cells and only skip rows without `<td>` cells here:

```
for row in soup('table')[5].findAll('tr'):
    tds = row('td')
    if not tds:
        continue
    print u' '.join([cell.string for cell in tds if cell.string])
```

This produces

```
United States, California
Va Long Beach Healthcare System
Long Beach, California, United States, 90822  
United States, Georgia
Gastrointestinal Specialists Of Georgia Pc
Marietta, Georgia, United States, 30060  
# .... 
Local Institution
Taipei, Taiwan, 100  
Local Institution
Taoyuan, Taiwan, 333  
United Kingdom
Local Institution
London, Greater London, United Kingdom, SE5 9RS
```

Comment: Thanks a million Martijn. Thanks a million. It worked!